# How do you avoid IF from evaluating macros?

Tags: clojure

If you run the following it only prints "foo":

```
(if true (println "foo") (println "bar"))
;foo
```

However if you pass macros in as the arguments to the if, it seems to evaluate both macros immediately.

```
(defmacro foo
  []
  (println "foo"))

(defmacro bar
  []
  (println "bar"))

(if true (foo) (bar))
;foo
;bar
```

How do you avoid running both macros and just evaluate the one for the true condition?

EDIT:

The main source of my confusion is that this would work in common lisp. I don't know how common lisp handles compiling macros differently but I'm guessing it has to do with more freedom not being on the JVM.

To clarify the actual code was to create forms of a certain type without quoting them as arguments. The code was being iterated on and was going to get more complicated, but in the current state was along the lines of:

```
(defmacro foo
  [arg1 arg2]
  `(quote (~arg1 ~arg2 [])))

(defmacro bar
  [arg1 arg2]
  `(quote (~(first arg1) ~arg2 [~(second arg1)])))

(defmacro foobar
  [arg1 arg2]
  `(if (list? '~arg1)
    (bar ~arg1 ~arg2)
    (foo ~arg1 ~arg2)))

(foobar FOO "bar") 
;; doesn't work since macros get compiled and you can't pass FOO as an argument to bar
(foobar (FOO "bar") "foobar")
;; (FOO "bar" ["foobar"])
```

I wanted both macros to not be expanded before evaluating the if since passing something other than a list to bar would cause an exception. I now understand that's not possible because expansion happens compile time. I've switched to using multimethods--which is more verbose, but more polymorphic I suppose.

Comment: Macros are run at compile time, not runtime. You can't avoid compiling something (your unconditional  `println` is running at compilation time, not evaluation time, here), but you *can* control what code is generated by the compiler (though in this case, your macro emits absolutely nothing).

Comment: Ok, that's what I was mistaken then. I think I need to rethink my code. If you want to post as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd need a macro _or_ a multimethod there -- at a brief read of your edited code, I'm not seeing anything you couldn't do with a regular function (albeit with not necessarily great runtime efficiency). Unless, I suppose, what you're expanding to or invoking can be a special form. Given a stronger definition / set of use cases around "foo", "bar" and "foobar", it might be possible to extend my answer to address your actual intent.

Comment: the multi method would be for dispatching different methods based on whether the argument is a list or not. The goal is to eventually create a basic DSL. I'm iterating over it and trying to replace macros where I can, but the point of these macros are to accept specific forms as arguments. For example in (foobar FOO "bar") FOO is not a symbol that can be resolved and you could not pass that into a function.

Comment: Makes sense. I'd consider doing things in a way that didn't have that constraint (using keywords rather than symbols, f'rinstance), but then, that's a matter of taste, and tastes vary.

Comment: BTW, if you really do need to trigger more compilation from runtime, well, that's what `eval` is for... with all its usual caveats.

Comment: Thanks. It actually has to do with abstracting compojure endpoints for distributed web services in a RESTful manner. It would end up looking something like (endpoint "/foobar" (GET id) (GET [name status]) (DELETE id) (POST :body). I might end up using keywords and symbols but I prefer the dsl to (:get 'id) (:get ['name 'status]) etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alan has the right of it (in terms of the immediate fix needed), but to speak to the reasoning:

Macros are evaluated at compile time, not runtime. It's patently impossible for something only known at runtime to control what's compiled, because all compilation is necessarily finished before runtime starts.

What you *can* do is make your `if` part of another macro, thus moving it to compile time as well.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the "syntax quote".  The code should look like this:

```
(defmacro foo
  []
  `(println "foo"))

(defmacro bar
  []
  `(println "bar"))

(if true 
  (foo) 
  (bar))
```

;=> foo

Comment: I guess I should clarify. My problem is I need the macro to be expanded after the if, not before. Quoting the println just expands to a form that's passed to the if before the if, so the macro is still expanded pre if. Leaving it unquoted shows when the expansion happens.

Comment: I'm not actually producing code that has side affects, it was just a way to figure out what was going on. The code is something more like: (if (list? arg) (do-list-thing-macro arg) (do-string-thing-macro arg))

Comment: I guess I'm not sure why you are using a macro in the first place....?  It sounds like you would probably be better off with regular functions.

Comment: Chalk it up to a poor question. To make the question simpler I used an example that just showed the issue but unfortunately caused a lot of confusion. I've updated the question to show something closer to the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Macros are abstraction on syntax. You use it when you see a pattern you often write, but because of argument evaluation you cannot use functions. Macros evaluate to code and there should not be side effects since you have no control over when it gets expanded (run).

`foo` and `bar` should have been functions. Then it will work as you intended.

```
(defn foo
  []
  (println "foo"))

(defn bar
  []
  (println "bar"))

(if true 
  (foo) 
  (bar)) ; prints "foo"
```

Using a macro when it's not needed is considered bad practice.

Comment: yea I understand that. It was just an example. I actually need macros.

Comment: @Nathanial basically the result from `(macroexpand '(foo))` should be the code you intended the macro to replace and it becomes `nil`